# why do we use the asterisk in sudo apt-get remove ros-*

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

we used asterisk in the following command
sudo apt-get remove ros-*
why do we use this asterisk

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/333367/why-do-we-use-the-asterisk-in-sudo-apt-get-remove-ros-*/) by [saikaushik](https://answers.ros.org/users/45828/saikaushik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-09-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In short: the asterisk tells `apt` to select all packages that *start with* `ros-`. So it selects not a single package, but *all* packages installed that have a name starting with `ros-`.

See [wikipedia/Regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) and [wikipedia/Glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) for more information.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [saikaushik](https://answers.ros.org/users/45828/saikaushik/) on 2019-09-19**:
Thanks for the response